# Unglücklich oder unglücklicherweise verloren?

Tags: adverb

Hi ich höre sehr oft bei Fußballspielen

1.) "Er hat unglücklich/verdient verloren."

sollte es nicht sein

2.) "Er hat unglücklicherweise/verdientermaßen verloren." ?

Kann mir jemand erklären warum der erste Satz richtig zu sein scheint? Denn ich selbt hätte den zweiten genommen.

Comment: Beide Sätze sind möglich und richtig. Der erste ist etwas kürzer und wird z.B. benutzt wenn eine Zeitungsmeldung etwas zu lang ist. Er kann aber nur im Zusammenhang mit dem Fußballverein benutzt werden, bei der Mannschaft muss die benutzt werden. Ein einzelner Spieler kann ja schlecht ein Spiel der Mannschaftssportart Fußball verlieren, da war schon die ganze Mannschaft beteiligt.

Comment: @Uwe: Der Verein, der Club, der Traktor, der Titelanwärter, der Meister, der Aufsteiger, der Absteiger, ... :)

Answer (score 7):

**Unglücklicherweise** ergreift Partei für den Verlierer. Ob er knapp oder durch Pech verloren hat, ist damit nicht ausgedrückt.

**Unglücklich verlieren** sagt man, wenn ein Unentschieden oder Sieg möglich schien, etwa dass die Manschaft dreimal den Pfosten getroffen hat, vom Schiedsrichter verpfiffen wurde oder durch eine Zufälligkeit, etwa eine Unebenheit im Boden oder auf den Platz stürmende Zuschauer um den Erfolg gebracht wurde.

Letzteren Ausdruck kann man auch anerkennend verwenden, wenn das Herz für den glücklichen Gewinner geschlagen hat.

Answer (score 2):

Im Deutschen können nicht nur Adverbien Adverbiale sein, sondern auch Adjektive.

- **Adjektiv**
  Eine **Wortart** (keine grammatische Funktion)
  Adjektive können als Attribute (»ein *schöner* Tag«), Prädikative (»der Tag ist *schön*«) und als Adverbiale (»Sie singt *schön*«) verwendet werden.
  Adjektive, die Attribute sind, werden flektiert (»ein *schöner* Tag«, »die *schönen* Tage«, »der *schöne* Tag«).
  Viele Adjektive kann man steigern (»Sie singt *schön*«, »Sie singt *schöner*«, »Sie singt *am schönsten*«)
- **Adverb**
  Eine **Wortart** (keine grammatische Funktion)
  Adverbien können keine Attribute sein (falsch: »das *ofte* Ereignis«), daher werden sie auch niemals flektiert. Am häufigsten werden sie als Adverbiale verwendet (»Das Ereignis findet *oft* statt«). Adverbien kann man im Allgemeinen nicht steigern, zu den seltenen Ausnahmen zählen *oft* (»Das Ereignis findet *öfter* statt«) und *wohl* (»Hier fühle ich mich *am wohlsten*«)
- **Adverbial**
  Eine **grammatische Funktion** (keine Wortart)
  Ein Adverbial ist ein Teil eines Satzes, der die näheren Umstände des Verbs beschreibt. Das kann ein Adjektiv sein (»Sie singt *schön*«), ein Adverb (»Sie singt *oft*«) oder auch eine Gruppe von mehreren Wörtern (»Sie singt *weil sie es kann*«)

Nur zur Sicherheit zwei weitere Definitionen:

- **Wortart**
  Ein Wort gehört einer bestimmten Wortart unabhängig vom grammatikalischen Kontext an, sogar dann, wenn es alleine, außerhalb eines Satzes steht (z.B. wenn es der Titel eines Wörterbucheintrags ist)
  Beispiele:

  - *»Baumes«* ist immer ein Substantiv, egal wo dieses Wort steht.
  - *»schlief«* ist immer ein Verb, egal wo dieses Wort steht.
  - *»schönste«* ist immer ein Adjektiv, egal wo dieses Wort steht.
- **grammatische Funktion**
  Das ist etwas, das ein Wort aufgrund seiner Stellung im Satz, und aufgrund seiner Beziehung zur grammatikalischen Umgebung inne hat.

Was mit *singen* funktioniert, funktioniert auch mit jedem anderen Verb, also auch mit *verlieren*:

- **Adjektive als Adverbiale:**

  > Er verliert *schnell.*
  >   Er verliert *gewaltig.*
  >   Er verliert *unglücklich.*
  >   Er verliert *verdient.*

  Dass es sich hier um Adjektive handelt, erkennt man daran, dass sie als Attribute verwendet werden können. Wenn eine Steigerung möglich ist, ist das ein weiteres Indiz:

  > der *schnellste* Verlust
  >   der *gewaltigere* Verlust
  >   der *unglücklichste* Verlust
  >   der *verdiente* Verlust
- **Adverbien als Adverbiale:**

  > Er verliert *immer.*
  >   Er verliert *trotzdem.*
  >   Er verliert *unglücklicherweise.*
  >   Er verliert *verdientermaßen.*

  Die Attribut-Probe offenbart, dass diese Wörter keine Adjektive (sondern Adverbien) sind. Keine der folgenden Nominalphrasen ist richtig:

  > <del>der *immere* Verlust</del>
  >   <del>der *trotzdeme* Verlust</del>
  >   <del>der *unglücklicherweise* Verlust</del>
  >   <del>der *verdientermaßene* Verlust</del>

Answer (score 2):

Mit *unglücklicherweise verloren* drückt der Sprecher seine Meinung zu der Niederlage aus. Er hätte sich lieber einen Sieg gewünscht.

Bei *unglücklich verlieren* hatte die unterlegene Mannschaft Pech. Sie hätte genauso gut gewinnen können, konnte ihre Chancen aber leider nicht nutzen. Im Extremfall hatte sie sogar wesentlich besser gespielt als der Sieger. Diese Formulierung verwenden Sportreporter gerne, wenn sie eine Niederlage als unerwartet oder gar ungerechtfertigt darstellen wollen, ohne dabei Partei für den Verlierer ergreifen zu müssen.

Zum Unterschied von *unglücklicherweise* und *unglücklich* noch ein weiteres Beispiel:

- *Ich bin unglücklicherweise gefallen*, heißt soviel wie dass ich das Pech hatte zu fallen.
- *Ich bin unglücklich gefallen*, besagt, dass ich nicht nur das Pech hatte zu fallen, sondern mir dabei noch größerer Schaden zugefügt wurde, als dies unter gewöhnlichen Umständen der Fall gewesen wäre.